# Concatenate ASCII to String for comparaison

Tags: c, string, arduino, comparison, ascii

I'm using Arduino with Serial BUS and trying to make it interact according to the word ASCII that I send on the bus. I went through many many websites and found a lot of solutions without be able to trully find what I'm looking for.

Exemple if I send "123":

```
char requestBuffer[10];    
void loop(){
   if (Serial.available() > 0){
       int bytesRead = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', requestBuffer, 10);

       char mott[3];
       mott[0] = (int)requestBuffer[0];
       mott[1] = (int)requestBuffer[1];
       mott[2] = (int)requestBuffer[2];

       Serial.println(mott); // it does print 123
       if ( mott == 123 ){   // doesn't works
           blablabla.
       }
   } 
}
```

I don't really know how to properly store in a variable what is typed in order to compare it. I'm not super friendly with C so maybe there are some ways to do that, that I didn't understand yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char mott[3];` needs to be `char mott[4] = {0};` else you don't have a NUL terminator in your `println` call. Currently the behaviour of your program is undefined. Your `println` currently works because of an unfortunate accident.

Once you have your `mott` array, use `int n = atoi(mott);` to convert the `char` string to an `int`. Here the array `mott` *decays* to a `char*` pointer, which is an acceptable type for `atoi`.

(The expression `mott == 123` is comparing the `char*` pointer to the first element of the `mott` array to 123, which it almost certainly isn't.)

Comment: This solution actually worked pretty fine, thanks mate. I never heard about atoi()